# Python : How to replace a piece of code when importing

Tags: python

I have two files, main.py and module.py. Module.py is erased and re-written from another program (Qt designer), meaning I can't modify it myself.

Because of a [Pyside-uic issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1174), I need to replace all calls to a function ( Qstring() ) by another one ( str() ) when  I import Module.py.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it once in this way:

Inside my main program:

```py
import module-fix.py
```

module-fix.py

```py
import module.py as module
def fix_func():
  pass
module.func = fix_func
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll accept this, but I hope someone find a better work-around, as it add a file only for 4 lines of code.